# Calculating revenue to include based on date timeframe

Tags: formula

I have created a new object in Salesforce to compare sales revenue against the Goal for a particular month. Each month has its own record with Sales Start Date the first of the month and Sales End Date the last of that month. I am trying to calculate total monthly revenue based on the transaction date and total sales revenue kept on an order object (every order is a record with total sales revenue and transaction date included).  Basically what I want to say is IF(Transaction Date is greater/equal to Sales Start Date and less/equal to Sales End Date, then add in the total sales revenue to give me a total for the month. Any ideas how I go about doing this?

Comment: I think the only way to do that as a no-coding solution would be to create a master-detail relationship between your 'month' object and your 'transaction', make each transaction a child of the relevant month object (assuming you can) and then do a rollup summary. Otherwise, i think you would have to do it programatically using a trigger or apex program by adding a lookup to 'month' on your transaction object and then summarising the transaction values by month.